# I want to add an image without using xml in mainactivity

Tags: java, android

I tried to do it by using ITexture and all.
I want to add an image but i don't want to use XML and i want to put this image in my screen without touching XML area?

Comment: Have you tried anything already? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I am trying to add an image. precisely i am working in previously written project where i have to add another intent and then add an image button. but as i said already written, so there is no XML was written for maintaining the buttons and image and all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setImage without Using ImageView on Your mainlayout.

```
LinearLayout someLinearLayout;
int setImage=R.drawable.ic_launcher;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    someLinearLayout=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.image1);
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams vp =  new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(vp);        
    imageView.setImageResource(setImage);
    someLinearLayout.addView(imageView);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
         iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
         Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Pics/Pic_1.jpg");
         iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
       ll.addView(iv, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```